# How to download pdf file using asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I upload file and stored in Data folder in server

File path:

```
Project Name
 |_bin
 |_css
 |_Data
   |_Mohamedfaisal.pdf
```

this is my asp.net code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.IO;
using System.Data;

namespace Expatriates {
 public partial class FileUploadForm: System.Web.UI.Page {
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {

  }

  protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
   if (FileUpload1.HasFile) {
    FileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Data/") + FileUpload1.FileName);
   }

   DataTable dt = new DataTable();
   dt.Columns.Add("File", typeof(string));
   dt.Columns.Add("size", typeof(string));
   dt.Columns.Add("type", typeof(string));

   foreach(string strFile in Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("~/Data/"))) {
    FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(strFile);

    dt.Rows.Add(fi.Name, fi.Length, fi.Extension);
   }

   GridView1.DataSource = dt;
   GridView1.DataBind();
  }

  protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e) {
   if (e.CommandName == "Download") {
    Response.Clear();
    Response.Write(e.CommandArgument);
    Response.ContentType = "application/octect-stream";
    Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "filename=" + e.CommandArgument);
    Response.TransmitFile(Server.MapPath("~/Data/") + e.CommandArgument); // error occured
    Response.End();
   }
  }
 }
}
```

Front End asp.net

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"     CodeBehind="FileUploadForm.aspx.cs" Inherits="Expatriates.FileUploadForm" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div style="font-family:Arial;">
        <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" />
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Upload"     OnClick="Button1_Click" />
        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand">
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="File">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CommandName="Download" Text='<%# Eval("File") %>'></asp:LinkButton>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Size" HeaderText="Size in Bytes" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Type" HeaderText="File Type" />
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

my front end design
[UI design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jiSop.png)

when I click that link it shows that following error message

> An exception of type 'System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException' occurred
>   in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Could not find a part of the path 'F:\Visual
>   Studio Project\Expatriates\Expatriates\Data\'.

Uploading file is working perfectly, But I am not getting a download.

Comment: Try with `Path.Combine(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Data/"));`

Comment: Did you debug and check that the File Name is there in e.CommandArgument?

Comment: @sachin: you are correct. It's not having file name. Now problem fixed. Thanks

Comment: @mohamedfaisal You should accept an answer if it solves your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only reason your code could fail would be if `e.CommandArgument` doesn't have a valid file name. I think the **Command Argument isn't being passed** for some reason, please look into your markup.

You have to explicitly specify `CommandArgument` for a `LinkButton` like this:

```
CommandArgument='<%# Eval("File") %>'
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't supply a commandArgument for your RowCommand event. Change

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CommandName="Download" Text='<%# Eval("File") %>'></asp:LinkButton>
```

to

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CommandName="Download" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("File") %>' Text='<%# Eval("File") %>'></asp:LinkButton>
```