# I'm trying to download PDF file using C# and asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

using the following code I'm trying to download pdf file from server path but after clicking on download button file not download but the code gets file name and file path.

I think I'm missing something in code so, please help me out
Thank you in advance..

code is :
protected void btn_Download_Template_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

````
{
     string mainPath = "";
     string fileName = "Self_Declaration.pdf";

     mainPath = Server.MapPath("~/Template/Self_Declaration.pdf");
     
     
     FileInfo file = new FileInfo(mainPath);
     if (file.Exists)
     {
         Response.Clear();
         Response.ClearHeaders();
         Response.ClearContent();
         Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename= ~/Template/Self_Declaration.pdf");
         Response.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/pdf");
         Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
         Response.WriteFile(file.FullName);
         Response.End();
}
else
     {
         Response.Write("This file does not exist.");
     }
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

Well I don't have enough reputation points to put this in the comment section, but I think your question has already been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39590539/how-to-download-pdf-file-using-asp-net)

Comment: I want to download file from folder that stored in Template folder not from database